# Dotted dash line in GraphView

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, paint, android-graphview

**I want a dotted line**, as described in [the official documentation](http://www.android-graphview.org/line-graph/):

```
    futureSeries.setDrawDataPoints(true);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{8, 5}, 0));
    futureSeries.setCustomPaint(paint);

    graph.addSeries(futureSeries);
```

**build.gradle:**

```
   compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.1'
```

**The result is not a dotted line:**

[image]

Something like this would be okay:

[image]

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I want a dotted line. But the result is a line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just apply [`LineGraphSeries#setDrawAsPath(true)`](https://github.com/appsthatmatter/GraphView/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jjoe64/graphview/series/LineGraphSeries.java#L654).

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{8, 5}, 0));

LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = ... // init

series.setDrawAsPath(true);
series.setCustomPaint(paint);

graphView.addSeries(series);
```

Result:

[image]